# How to get matchit to work

Tags: plugin-matchit

I am trying and failing to get matchit to work.

I have the plugin at:

```
$ locate matchit.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim80/macros/matchit.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim80/pack/dist/opt/matchit/plugin/matchit.vim
```

I have tried ~/.virc:

```
packadd! matchit
```

Does it work with "vi" and not "vim"?

Comment: I think you need to use `~/.vimrc` for `vim`. And I don't think you need to do `packadd` on matchit, it's used by default. Just make sure the version of vim you're using is the full-version, not one of those `vim-minimal` etc.

Comment: `:h matchit-install`

Comment: I use vi, not vim. So it will not work with vi then? I have always reverted back to vi after trying vim. Can't recall why. I might have to try it again. I think it may have been the syntax highlighting. Maybe I can disable that? I suppose that's a different question ...

Comment: UPDATE: I got it to work with vim but not vi. It does not appear to work with vi. I had to install vim-enhanced, add "packadd! matchit" to ~/.vimrc and then running vim (instead of vi) worked.

Answer (score 6):

As @Klaus already mentioned in his comment, the correct file name for the initialization file is `~/.vimrc`. The file `~/.virc` is not loaded at all.

You can check the loaded files by executing the command

```
:scriptnames
```

Also the matchit plugin is an optional plugin. The path to it contains `/opt/`.

```
/usr/share/vim/vim80/pack/dist/opt/matchit/plugin/matchit.vim
" matchit is optional          ^^^
```

So you need `packadd! matchit`.

BTW: If the path to a plugin contains `start` instead of `opt` it would be enabled by default. AFAIK the default Vim contains no plugin that is enabled by default. This might be different for binary distributions/packages build by third parties.